# Reference the iteration number in a Hashicorp Packer for_each loop

Tags: terraform, packer, hashicorp, hashicorp-packer

consider the following HCL Map:

```
locals {
  disks = {
    sda = {
      size = 1024
      thin = true
    }
    sdb = {
      size = 2048
      thin = false
    }
  }
}
```

and the following `source "vsphere-iso" "linux-rhel"` dynamic storage block:

```
  dynamic "storage" {
    for_each = local.disks
    content {
      disk_size             = storage.value.size
      disk_thin_provisioned = storage.value.thin
      disk_controller_index = ???
    }
  }
```

What value can I substitute ??? for that will increment with each iteration?
I know `count.index` works with a `count=XX` loop, but would like to not have to add the index value to the the map, since it's just calculated anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add `index` to `local.disks`:

```
locals {
  disks = {
    sda = {
      size = 1024
      thin = true
      index = 0
    }
    sdb = {
      size = 2048
      thin = false
      index = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively iterate over `keys`:

```
 dynamic "storage" {
    for_each = keys(local.disks)
    content {
      disk_size             = local.disks[storage.value].size
      disk_thin_provisioned = local.disks[storage.value].thin
      disk_controller_index = storage.key # key will be index number
    }
  }
```

but the `storage.key` will not necessarily represent apparent order as in `local.disks`, because maps do not have order.

Comment: Because of the "...maps do not have order" statement, I think it's best I just add the index value to each map item. this would have the added advantage of putting multiple drive on on disk controller.  thanks @Marcin.